# Problem about applying Fubini's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to apply to Fubini's theorem to the following integral:
$$
\int_{|x-y|\geq r}\int_{a|x-y|}^{b|x-y|}|f(y)||h(t)|dtdy,
$$
where $a,b,t>0,~~a<b$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My answer is the following. But i am not sure if this one is true?

$$
\int_{|x-y|\geq r}\int_{a|x-y|}^{b|x-y|}|f(y)||h(t)|dtdy=\int_{r}^{\infty}|h(t)|\left(\int_{r\le |x-y|<\frac{t}{a} }|f(y)|dy\right)dt.
$$

Comment: This is correct according to Tonelli's theorem, a Corollary of Fubini's theorem, which applies when all functions to integrate are non-negative as here.